# Python request.headers differs from what I see in Chrome

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome, python-requests, request-headers

Just wondering if anyone could explain why I navigate to a webpage using Chrome and the request headers include Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Connection, Cookie, Host, Referer, Upgrade-Insecure-Request, and User-Agent but when I make a request via Python and print request.headers it only returns Connection, Accept-Encoding, Accept, and User-Agent even if I set the User-Agent to the same one I see in Chrome. Also I'm wondering if it's possible to return those request headers I see in Chrome rather than those I see in Python. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your using two different libraries (Chrome's internal http library and `requests`). It's very rare for two unrelated libraries to send the same set of headers, especially when one is from a browser. You could manually set those headers in `requests` but I'm not sure what you're trying to do

Comment: Almost everything I see in Chrome request headers can be manually set beside the cookie. I was trying to see if there was a way to make a request to the page, get the cookie from the header, and make all future requests with that cookie in the header. Do you happen to know if this would be possible with the urllib module rather than requests?